# Can't install docker - Permission denied?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to install docker-machine following the [guide](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/).

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
> chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Error:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine: Permission denied

Why? How can resolve this?

I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in [issue 652](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/652)

Either you chown that folder

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Or (better), as in [this PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1249/files)

> Note: If you get a "Permission denied" error, your `/usr/local/bin` directory probably isn't writable and you'll need to install Compose as the superuser.
>   Run `sudo -i`, then the two commands above, then `exit`.